# Oracle connection using Nhibernate. ORA-12514

Tags: nhibernate, .net-3.5, connection-string, oracle9i

I'm trying to connect my application with an Oracle database using NHIBERNATE 3.1.0.4000 version and I got this error:

> ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

I've already tried some connection strings and none of them work:

- SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MySID)));uid=MyUser;pwd=MyPassword;
- Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MySID)));User Id=MyUser;Password=MyPassword;
- SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MySID)));uid=MyUser;pwd=MyPassword;
- Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};Server=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MySID)));Uid=MyUser;Pwd=MyPassword;

The properties I have are User, Password, Host, Port and SID. In other words, there is no TNS. My options is to connect directly.

Some informations may are important:

- I'm running it using a test project.
- I'm using VPN connection to database server.
- I can connect to the server via TOAD Client fine
- My project was built with .NET framework 3.5
- The oracle version is 9i

Installed binaries files:

- Castle.Core
- Iesi.Collection
- Nhibernate
- Nhibernate.ByteCode.Castle
- Oracle.DataAcess

Development enviroment is:

- Windows 7 64 bits
- Visual Studio 2010 Premium

hibernate.hbm.xml file content:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
    <session-factory name="NHibernate.Test">
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">
      SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=MyHost)(PORT=MyPort))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MySID)));uid=MyUser;pwd=MyPassword;
    </property>
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.Oracle9iDialect</property>
        <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
        <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Thank you all is advanced! I hope so much be helped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem.

Besides the binaries files that I wrote before, I just added the System.Data.OracleClient reference to repository's and test's project and it magically worked!

However, Is important to say that is extremely important move the Visual Studio to a folder without parenthesis, because it was drive me for another error. When you install it in a 64 bits platform, the Visual Studio is installed  inside "C:\ProgramFiles(86x)\" folder, and it is a problem for the Oracle Instant Client.

Answer (score 2):

- Confirm wether you have a SID or a SERVICE_NAME (What are you using in TOAD?) and pick the appropriate connection string.
- Check that the name matches the listener exactly.
- If the server is in a domain, add the domain to the SID/SERVICE_NAME: MySID.MY.DOMAIN.COM
- If you're already doing that, try removing it.

Comment: Hi @Fredy Treboux! Thank you for the answer. I'm pretty newer with Oracle. So forgive me for any stupid question. I don't know the SERVICE_NAME and the SID is the same used in TOAD. There is any way that I can get the SERVICE_NAME from TOAD or anything? How do I check the listener? I tried to add the domain to the SID and it didn't work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure if I'll be able to help you troubleshoot this further without having the chance to play around with the system, but I can try. I just  mentioned some things that have bit me in the past, Oracle tends to be obscure, at least to me.
Are you always getting the same error?, Can you paste a screenshot (without real info) of how you connect through TOAD?

Comment: Yes, I have been always getting the same error. Of course I can, [here it is!](http://db.tt/26NQiQOF)